# Methods of namedtuple not listed by dir()

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

In  [8.3. collections — Container datatypes — Python 3.6.4rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple),
it specifies 5 methods of `namedtuple`.

```
namedtuple_methods = {'_fields', '_make', '_replace', '_asdict', '_source'}
```

Nevertheless, the methods cannot be acquired by `dir` method

```
from collections import namedtuple
set(dir(namedtuple)) & namedtuple_methods
In [64]: set(dir(namedtuple)) & namedtuple_methods
Out[64]: set()
```

They share no intersection.

Interestingly, a particular `namedtuple` lists the methods

```
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'name, author')
In [70]: set(dir(Book)) & namedtuple_methods
Out[70]: {'_asdict', '_fields', '_make', '_replace', '_source'}
```

What's the machenism behind?

Answer (score 2):

`namedtuple` is a factory function (literally, there is a function in the source code that begins `def namedtuple(`), it's not a class on its own (it creates subclasses of `tuple`, but it is not a `tuple` or a `namedtuple`). Plain `def`-ed functions wouldn't have any such special methods.